# SSL handshake failed from Server

Tags: apache

Need to understand why this error comes, I am curious because i did set up two server today and one is working fine but the other giving "SSL handshake failed"

Is this issue because the certificate was not generated properly or something else, any insight will be helpful

Comment: Check your error log for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and just barely figured it out.  I used the methods described here: [SSL HandShake exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775483/ssl-handshake-exception).

I used the tool https://github.com/rabbitfighter81/SSLKeytool and generated a new key pair and keystore.  I set the location of the keystore for APACHEDS in Apache Studio.