# Java error when running a javaprofile script involving ping authentication

Tags: java

we're getting this error when we try to invoke any java script on our Linux box.

Is anyone familiar with this error, and what can be done about it? Their saying it has to do with a patch.

[image]

If this means we have to reinstall the certificate, where can I find out how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found this link and it looks very similar to the issue I'm having.

[SSL HandShake exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775483/ssl-handshake-exception)

I'm going to follow the advice from this fix.

If anyone has any extra info please feel free to comment.